# How to get an empty result table with FULL JOIN?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, inner-join

I will show you the content of some tables.

```
Bolek=> SELECT id, description from "TOMBInput";
 id |    description    
----+-------------------
  1 | Virtual Input 111
  2 | Virtual Input 112
  3 | Virtual Input 113
  4 | Virtual Input 114
(4 rows)

Bolek=> SELECT id, setup_id FROM "TRBTOMBConnection";
 id | setup_id 
----+----------
  1 |        1
  2 |        1
  3 |        1
  4 |        1
(4 rows)

Bolek=> SELECT id, setname FROM "Setup";
 id |   setname   
----+-------------
  1 | SETUP_00001
(1 row)

Bolek=> SELECT id, setup_id FROM "Run";
 id | setup_id 
----+----------
  1 |        1
(1 row)
```

My query [1] is

```
SELECT
  "TOMBInput".id AS tombinput_id,
  "TRBTOMBConnection".id AS trbtombconnection_id,
  "Setup".id AS setup_id,
  "Run".id AS run_id
FROM "TOMBInput" 
  INNER JOIN "TRBTOMBConnection" ON "TOMBInput".id = "TRBTOMBConnection".tombinput_id
  FULL JOIN "Setup" ON "TRBTOMBConnection".id = "Setup".id
  FULL JOIN "Run" ON "Setup".id = "Run".id AND "Run".id = 1;
```

Result table

```
 tombinput_id | trbtombconnection_id | setup_id | run_id 
--------------+----------------------+----------+--------
            1 |                    1 |        1 |      1
            2 |                    2 |          |       
            3 |                    3 |          |       
            4 |                    4 |          |       
(4 rows)
```

The question is
I would like to have table like

```
 tombinput_id | trbtombconnection_id | setup_id | run_id 
--------------+----------------------+----------+--------
            1 |                    1 |        1 |      1
            2 |                    2 |        1 |      1 
            3 |                    3 |        1 |      1 
            4 |                    4 |        1 |      1 
(4 rows)
```

because "TRBTOMBConnection" has got 4 rows with setup_id==1
and "Run" has got setup_id==1.

What is more, now when I change last line (in my query [1])

```
FULL JOIN "Run" ON "Setup".id = "Run".id AND "Run".id = 2;
```

(in "Run" table we haven`t got id==2) the result of query is

```
 tombinput_id | trbtombconnection_id | setup_id | run_id 
--------------+----------------------+----------+--------
            1 |                    1 |        1 |       
            2 |                    2 |          |       
            3 |                    3 |          |       
            4 |                    4 |          |       
              |                      |          |      1
(5 rows)
```

And it`s ok, because I used FULL JOIN.

But in this case when I run my query [1]

I would like to have an empty result table because "Run" hasn't got id==2 and it hasn't got any sense to show table because everything is starting from Run.

How to change my query [1]?

Comment: Ihis is an example of why it is a bad idea to ever use the column name ID (it's a SQL antipattern). I can't tell from looking at it what the key relationships are and clearly you can't either since you are getting incorrect results.

Comment: why are you using `FULL JOIN` here and not just `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @HLGEM i actually find it confusing _not_ to use `id` as the primary key name, since then it looks to me like a foreign key!  :)

Comment: @eevee, sugest you read up on why it is  poor practice: http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers-ebook/dp/B00A376BB2/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1396038398&sr=1-1&keywords=sql+antipatterns

Comment: @Eevee: What you report is the result of bad habits, not an argument. `id` is not a descriptive name. Once you join a couple of tables (which is *what you do* in SQL) you end up with a bunch of useless, ambiguous column names. You need to deal out aliases to be able to work with that, which will be inconsistent and error-prone. That's a bad design. Just because some half-wit ORMs are using `id` doesn't make it any smarter.

Comment: orrr just use the table name, which is what you'd probably be embedding in the column name anyway

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I actually find the use of `id` not that terrible when it comes to joining.  You wind up with joins like `from foo join bar on foo.id = bar.foo_id`. I think it's not that much worse than `from foo join bar on foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id`. But I agree that it does get confusing and cumbersome for the columns in the select list.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: With `foo_id` it can be simpler yet: `FROM foo JOIN bar USING (foo_id)` ...

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing IDs:

```
SELECT
  "TOMBInput".id AS tombinput_id,
  "TRBTOMBConnection".id AS trbtombconnection_id,
  "Setup".id AS setup_id,
  "Run".id AS run_id
FROM "TOMBInput" 
  INNER JOIN "TRBTOMBConnection" ON "TOMBInput".id = "TRBTOMBConnection".tombinput_id
  INNER JOIN "Setup" ON "TRBTOMBConnection".setup_id = "Setup".id
  INNER JOIN "Run" ON "Setup".id = "Run".setup_id AND "Run".id = 1;
```

I see no reason for full outer joins here.

Comment: Oops, I was confusing the IDs, too. Thanks user3455638, I've corrected my SQL statement.